# How to Add a day and using format fct in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to add or retry  a day in acces vba but access gives me an error "Error syntax - Operator missing"

I have retry and add some quote but no result

> SELECT Employee_Data.[Employee Number],Employee_Data.Leave    FROM
>   Employee_Data   WHERE (([Date_Leave]=""#"" & Format([Date_Leave] -
>   1,""dd/mm/yyyy"") & ""#""));

"Error syntax - Operator missing"

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to ask here, but this doesn't seem to be an actual question or contain enough code for anyone to work off of. If you provide some more information I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but it seems you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT Employee_Data.[Employee Number], Employee_Data.Leave 
FROM Employee_Data 
WHERE [Date_Leave] = DateAdd("d", -1, Date())
```

[Check this link for details](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php)